# Вывод вводимого текста

Tags: javascript

```
let to_complete =this.to_complete = document.getElementById('to_complete');
    to_complete.addEventListener('click', add2)
    function add2(){
        let out = this.out = document.getElementById('out');
    let textarea = this.textarea = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
    if(textarea){
        this.out+=textarea;
    }else{
        return false
    }
    }
```

Данный код должен выводить текст из textarea в div с id ="out", но он не работает. Почему?
Если надо, могу предоставить весь код.

Comment: Слева от ответов на Ваши вопросы есть знак "галочка". Он сделан для Вас. Пользуйтесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let to_complete = this.to_complete = document.getElementById('to_complete');
to_complete.addEventListener('click', add2)

function add2() {
  let out = this.out = document.getElementById('out');
  let textarea = this.textarea = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
  if (textarea) {
    this.out.textContent += textarea;
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="to_complete">Complete</button>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<div id="out"></div>
```